# MARTE specification implemented by Papyrus

Tags: xml, eclipse, profile, uml, papyrus

i am new with MARTE and i read the specification related to time modeling subprofile promoted by OMG .

i use papyrus for MARTE i wonder if there is practical example for implementing these specification to begin with?
i failed in finding example through Google search

Comment: Hi! Did you find any examples?:)